# What is "Init for Update" thread state in mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Our production server gets stuck on `Init for update` state whenever we start a query like

```
update 
    <some_big_table> 
set 
    <primary_key> = <some_sequence>.nextval 
order by 
    <some_indexed_field>
```

While this the query is stuck are this state, all other queries get stuck at `commit` or `writing to binlog` state.

I couldn't find any relevant documentation for the same either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATEing` or `DELETEing` all of a big table takes a long time.  It is busy copying over every row in case of rollback.  Wait.

Is there some reason for using a sequence instead of an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Is there some reason for renumbering the table?

Neither of those is needed in normal MySQL operation.

To leave the existing column intact, but add a new id that is the PK:

```
ALTER TABLE t
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: I'm converting a table with random keys to auto increment. Before alter, i was setting primary key as numeric values order by modified timestamp

Comment: @HimanshuMishra - Alter the PK column to `INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`; it will do the sequencing automatically.

Comment: It currently has non-numeric strings which break the alter. I've done the above query in chunks of 1000s however.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra - I added a suggestion.